# jquery ajax dont work without firebug break point

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, firebug

I am using following method to call the php:

```
function validateEmaiAjax(email){
    val = null;
    $("#warning").load("https://localhost/Continental%20Tourism/register_ajax.php",{email: email}, function(rspns, stat, xml){
        val = rspns;
    });

    if(val == ".")
        return true;
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

my php code is:

```
<?php
    $dbc = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","continental_tourism") OR die(mysqli_connect_error());

    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];

    $query = "SELECT email FROM customer_info WHERE email = '$email' ";

    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) OR die(mysqli_error($dbc));

    if(mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0)
        echo "Email address exists!";
    else
        echo ".";   
?>
```

Basically this do check the database and if email exists shows "Email address exists!" if not I want to `return true`(so I echo "." and compare it). The weird thing is if i put a break point using firebug near `if(val == ".")` program works correctly and returns true. If I remove that break point function always return false. I cant understand why this happens. Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you have this problem is because you have performed an **asynchronous** request. This means that the `if(rspns == ".")` will be reached before the response has been received from the server, and the result will always be `false`.

In order to wrap this code in a function the returns a boolean and does not require a callback function (a blocking procedure) you will need to use a synchronous request:

```
function validateEmaiAjax(email) {

  // This is the correct way to initialise a variable with no value in a function
  var val;

  // Make a synchronous HTTP request
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://localhost/Continental%20Tourism/register_ajax.php",
    async: false,
    data: {
      email: email
    },
    success: function(response) {
      // Update the DOM and send response data back to parent function
      $("#warning").html(response);
      val = response;
    }
  });

  // Now this will work
  if(val == ".") {
    return true;
  } else {
    $("#warning").show();
    return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: Great article. Thanks for such a explain. Now I got the thing. Thanks again.

Comment: OMG - so much time spent on so simple a solution: adding 'async: false,' fixed my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why this

```
else {
    return false;
    $("#warning").show();
}
```

`$("#warning").show();` will never be executed.

EDIT : There ya go :

```
function validateEmaiAjax(email){
    var URL     = 'https://localhost/Continental%20Tourism/register_ajax.php';
    var Args    = {email: email}

    $('#warning').load(URL, Args, function(html){
        if(html == '.'){
            return true;
        } else {
            $('#warning').show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

Or you can try this also :

```
function validateEmaiAjax(email){
    var URL     = 'https://localhost/Continental%20Tourism/register_ajax.php';
    var Args    = {email: email}

    $.ajax({
        url:     URL,
        type:    'GET'
        data:    Args,
        success: function(html){
            if(html == '.'){
                return true;
            } else {
                $('#warning').show();
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make that code work you should use the $.ajax method instead of load and set async to false to make it wait for the response.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
 url:"https://localhost/Continental%20Tourism/register_ajax.php",
 async: false,
 data: {email: email}, 
 success: function(rspns, stat, xml){ 
   val = rspns; 
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your function keeps running and hits the `if(val == ".")` before it's gotten the ajax response back. You need to but that whole if statement inside the ajax callback function.

```
function validateEmaiAjax(email){
    var success;
    $("#warning").load("https://localhost/Continental%20Tourism/register_ajax.php",{email: email}, function(rspns, stat, xml){
        if(rspns == ".")
            success = true;
        else {
            $("#warning").show();
            success = false;
        }
    });
    return success;
}
```

Also swapped the warning show and return so it would execute

Comment: This still won't fix the problem. `validateEmaiAjax()` will now return `undefined`

Comment: @idrumgood you're still returning the variable before the AJAX response actually sets it.

Comment: @idrumgood I edit my code as you say. But still wont work. Still if i put a break point it'll work.

Comment: Since the `.load` function can't directly return a value, you may have to restructure your other code slightly to adjust for this. My code will, however, fix the problem you asked about in your post.