# Ajax call works in IE and Chrome (and only in Firefox when adding breakpoint in debug mode at end of ajax call)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, model-view-controller

I currently have the following code that works in IE and Chrome. 
The following issue is only within Firefox (which weirdly enough I can make it work in Firefox when in Debug mode and I add a breakpoint at the end of the ajax call shown in comments below). I believe it might have something to do with the ajax call below (where it errors). (SEE CODE COMMENTS FOR DETAILS).

I have the following code that receives the data from the forms and sends it to another JavaScript function to send the data back to MVC controller function that adds a user into a database.

```
$('#addUserSubmit').click(function () {
    var tagId = $(this).closest('form').find('input[name="userTag"]').val();
    var adminUser = $(this).closest('form').find('input[name="userName"]').val();
    AddUser(tagId, adminUser);
});

function AddUser(tagId, adminUser) {
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        'tagId': tagId,
        'adminUser': adminUser
    });
    $.ajax({ //HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS (After it goes through to set all of the variables below).
        type: "POST",
        url: "/UsersAccounts/AddUser",
        data: data,
        success: function (outVal) {
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest + textStatus + errorThrown);
        },
        contentType: 'application/json'
    }); //IF I ADD A BREAKPOINT HERE IT WILL WORK IN GOING TO THE MVC 
        //FUNCTION TO BELOW AND IT WILL WORK AS INTENDED (BUT IF I RUN 
        //THE CODE NORMALLY OR WITHOUT A BREAKPOINT HERE IT WILL ALERT 
        //WITH THE ERROR ABOVE).
}

    [HttpPost]
    public String AddUser(int tagId, string adminUser){
        if (tagId > 0){
            try{
                using (TubeBPC db = new TubeBPC()){
                    Users user = new Users() {TAGID=tagId, AdminUser=adminUser };
                    db.Users.Add(user);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return "success";
                }
            }
            catch(Exception dbe){
                throw dbe;
            }
        }
        else{
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("TagID is not a positive number");
        }
     }
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do more research and found this answer to be the solution.

"In order to wrap this code in a function the returns a boolean and does not require a callback function (a blocking procedure) you will need to use a synchronous request"

[jquery ajax dont work without firebug break point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195730/jquery-ajax-dont-work-without-firebug-break-point)

Hope it helps someone else!

Comment: Unfortunly I don't see how it could be a solution